# Responsive HTML5 Video

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a video fill the entire window width and height. The video should resize, if the window is resized. Therefore it might even have to change its aspect ratio. I got scrolling bars on the right, which should be removed somehow.

This is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <video autoplay loop id="bgvid">
        <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
video#bgvid {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: -100;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/6u1krL0L/

Answer (score 0):

To fill the complete window you should ensure that your video have the same aspect ratio that the window, It could be tricky.

I think the best option is ensure to fill just the width or just the height and then fill the background with black color.

Try the following:
html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <video autoplay loop id="bgvid">
    <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
  background-color: black;
}
video#bgvid {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: That isn't exactly what I'm looking for, since it only works for resizing the width of the window